# respawn_delay does not delay the respawn!

Tags: ros, roslaunch, respawn, roslauch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a new .launch element (only in Indigo) that delays the repawn of a node. However, it doesn't do what it says.

This is a demo part of the .launch file I have: Is there anything I'm missing?

```
<node pkg="res_prj" type="init_tf_broadcaster" name="init_tf_br"
 respawn="true" respawn_delay="20"/>
```

I expect the node `init_tf_br` respawn after 20 secs, but it starts immediately once it dies.

Thanks in advance.

Reference: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186427/respawn_delay-does-not-delay-the-respawn!/) by [emacsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3662/emacsd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 194 on 2014-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like that change was introduced three days ago, and hasn't been released yet: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/446

Until the ros_comm maintainers do the next release, you should be able to test it if you get the latest version of ros_comm from source.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [emacsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3662/emacsd/) on 2014-07-13**:
You're right!

Thank you.